# How to find documents where value exist in one field (product) but not in the other (companyName)...

Tags: solr, solr4

...AND show the companyName for the documents returned.

Current example of search performed:

```
product:Toys AND NOT companyName:Toys
```

What I expect to get is a list of documents that contain the term "Toys" in their product field but not in their companyName field. At this point I believe that this is exactly what is happening but the returned results do not contain a companyName. Am I using the wrong syntax?

Current results:

```
companyName: {}
product: Children Toys

companyName: {}
product: Toys
```

Expected results:

```
companyName: xyz ltd.
product: Children Toys

companyName: abc ltd.
product: Toys
```

Comment: Use product:Toys AND -companyName:Toys

Comment: I've tried both (sorry should have mentioned that) - both have the same outcome.

Comment: try +product:Toys -companyName:Toys

Comment: is the companyName field `stored`?

Comment: This must be more schema related issue than query related, can you post your schema

Comment: @sidgate and Oussama - Thank you, looks like it was a schema issue. I had a dynamicField which, used a wildcard to, capture the companyName field and set stored to false. I'll edit my morphlines scirpt to change the name of that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLR Fields must be `stored` so that the values are returned in the results.